# set label devexpress not affected with post back c#

Tags: c#, postback

how to make label devexpress not affected by post back or refresh page when click button save.

i have a button prompt, when the button prompt click, will set text in my label.
and when the button save click, before insert in to table.my form stop cause the validate. and then  my text on lable is lost

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btShowModal" Height="23" Width="25" runat="server" Text="..." AutoPostBack="False" UseSubmitBehavior="false">
                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { ShowLoginWindow(); }" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblUserName" Text=""></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

Comment: The DevExpress ASPxLabel is a tricky beast - the client side and server side values aren't kept in sync.  Easiest way to handle this is through a callback.

Comment: Or set the value in the `ShowLoginWindow` JS function.

Comment: how to get text from devexpress label ?
im try this >>> var getText = document.getElementById("lblUserName"); but its not work

Comment: I'd use the `ClientInstanceID` property for the `ASPxLabel` and then use the `SetText` method - like this `<dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblUserName" ClientInstanceName="lblUserName" runat="server" />` and then in the JS: `lblUserName.SetText('some text');`.

Comment: okey, thanks Tim... it work :)